# Is Islamic spiritual space immune to Hindu , Christian and Buddhist influence?

Tags: allah, scripture

Islamic scriptures are closed i.e. they are self sufficient to explain all phenomenon. They do not need help of other religious doctrines. Islamic scriptures do not need reference to Hindu or Christians or Buddhists directly. However the reality is different. In reality there are religions other than Islam. Today’s spiritual space is not only made up Allah but also Ram, Jesus and Buddha. Considering this my question is the following :

Is Islamic spiritual space immune to Hindu , Christian and Buddhist influence ? Are the Hindu , Muslim , Christian and Buddhist gods interacting with each other in some way? Does a prayer sent by ,let us say a Christian , influence Allah ? (Or does a prayer sent by Hindu , influence Allah?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core belief of Islam is:

> لا إله إلا الله
>
> There is no god, except Allah

So if they do not exist, they also do not interact with each other nor with Allah.

If a non-Muslim prays to a false diety, then that false diety does not hear it nor has the power to grant it. However, Allah hears it and may grant what has been asked for, and He does this because of various reasons.